# How to set UICollectionView padding UIEdgeInsets

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hello I have `UIControllerView` , i set `UIEdgeInsets` with under below codes;

```
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
  self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 100, right: 10)
```

my ContentView codes

```
 let contentWidth = maxWidthInASection
    let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections())
    self.contentSize = CGSize(width: Double(contentWidth), height: contentHeight)
    self.contentSize.height = CGFloat(Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections()))
```

But doesnt work user didnt select bottom side `cells` so when user scrolling auto goes bottom side cells i need to add bottom padding size `50- 100 px` like empty area.

Also second is ;

> When users scrolling collection view cells after collection view goes first opened position i want to disable it if user touch and move collection view anywhere must be stay there dont be goes firstly position ?

My sample picture under below for bottom padding

[image]

How can i do it ?

Thank you !

Comment: You will have a collection view delegate method 
- collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:. Here find if it is the last indexPath. And if yes, then you can increase collectionView or inside scrollViews height or modify contentSize.

Comment: you can also add, number of items as requiredItemCount + 10. So additional rows will be created. but inside itemAtIndexPath you can check if indexPath in less than requiredItemCount then return cell. else return nil.

Comment: @user3300864 i added  contentview codes  maybe need to change them can u see in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let flow: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = CollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
     flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: i added contentview codes  maybe need to change them your code dont work

Answer (score 1):

You should compute the height. For the bigger screen, more can be seen. So it will not do it automatically.